# ios 13 navigation bar not translucent along with the status bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, swiftui

I tried to implement my own navigation view in swiftui. But the status appears not translucent as the navigation bar is.

[image]

With `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)`, it worked as I expected.

[image: with <code>.edgesIgnoringSafeArea</code>]

But i wonder what's wrong with my custom view to make this happen.

```swift
struct ExampleNavigationView<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    private var content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content){
        self.content = content
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        let contentViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contentViewController)
        navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        contentViewController.navigationItem.title = "Search"
        return navigationController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ExampleNavigationView>) {}
}
```